# Formula that looks for any matching substrings between two cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to compose a formula that compares the substrings in two cells.

Substrings in each cell are separated by a space.

The formula should return TRUE if any substring in one cell also matches a substring in the other cell.

I intend to use the formula to conditionally format cells.

For example,

- if `A1` contains `"foo bar"`,
- and `B1` contains `"foo blah blah"`
- then the formula returns TRUE (both contain `"foo"`)
- and conditional formatting is applied to `B1`

I tried the following formula but it returns TRUE only if `B1="foo"` and FALSE if `"foo"` is a substring:

```
 =IF(FIND(B1,A1),1)>0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update**

I realize that I left out important details for this problem. I also need this formula to:

1. conditionally apply across an entire cell range `B1:D1`
2. be case-insensitive
3. allow a comma-separated keyword list on cell `A1`

Thanks to [@doubleunary](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/269219/doubleunary) I was able to adapt their answer to suit my specific needs as follows:

```
=regexmatch($A$1, substitute("(?i)\b(" & B1 & ")\b", " ", "|"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to create a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), like this:

```
=regexmatch(A1, substitute("\b(" & B1 & ")\b", " ", "|"))
```

When `B1` is `foo bar`, the regex is `\b(foo|bar)\b`.

See [regexmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).

Comment: I've added some clarifying comments to my question above, and the following formula works:

=regexmatch($A$1, substitute("(?i)\b(" & B1 & ")\b", " ", "|"))

Comment: Glad that you have a solution. Going forward, please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 0):

[@doubleunary's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172108/) is a good one.

The approach below uses [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) to convert the individual cells into arrays of substrings

## Substrings to Arrays

```
=LEN(
   FILTER(
     SPLIT(A1," "),
     COUNTIF(SPLIT(B1," "),
       SPLIT(A1," "))))
```

1. The [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) Function returns an array of matching substrings or `#N/A` if no matches.
2. [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) returns the length of the first matching substring or `#N/A`.
3. Conditional formatting interprets any non-zero number returned by [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) as TRUE and anything else, including `#N/A`, as FALSE.